# Android/Java - how to append HTML code to my linearlayout?

Tags: java, android, html, xml

So I have some strings in Java and I want to append to the screen along with some HTML elements (such as `<br>`). The linear layout variable is just:

```
main_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.main_layout);
```

And I'm simply trying to add TextViews, but for setText I'd like to be able to place HTML in there. I've heard this can be done, I would just really like some examples to point me in the right direction. Also, how can I dynamically style these xml text elements (similar to javascript and html)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add HTML into TextViews using [`HTML.fromHTML(source)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html) which returns a `Spanned` but I'm not sure what HTML tags it can/can't deal with (bold, italic, underlines and sub/superscript are definitely supported). The [`Spanned`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) can be styled I think, but I'm not sure how. Also be careful with sub/superscript as these tend not to show properly without altering the `TextView`'s line spacing.

Comment: Can I do line breaks? That's the biggest thing I need right now really. Also, do you have an example of how I would insert a line break? Thanks

Comment: If you just need a line break, you don't have to use HTML, just use `textView.setText(string1 + "\n" + string2)`. If you do want to use HTML, use `textView.setText(HTML.fromSource(string1 + "&lt;br/>" + string2))`